# Use Object in vector in loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector, stdvector

Currently, i have a loop iterating through a vector, and i'm trying to find the index of an object, while i'm in the loop, to delete it. How can i go about this?

Here's my code :

```
for (Object &a : objectDict)
    {
        a.setTime(theTime);

        double tempMoveX = 0, tempMoveZ = 0, tempUX = 0,tempUZ = 0;

        for (Object &b : objectDict)
        {
            if (a != b)
            {
                ...
                    debug << fixed << setprecision(20) <<  "Collision" << endl;
                    a.appendMass(b.getMass());

                    objectDict.erase(find(objectDict.begin(), objectDict.end(), b));
                ...
```

Thats the important part. How can i erase object b from the vector?

Comment: you don't need two for loops, just use find/find_if then erase

Comment: The two loops is because i'm using a elsewhere, i'm just interested in the deleting of b. I've tried find/find_if, but i'm getting Invalid operand between Object and const Object.

Comment: what kind of `b` do you want to erase?

Comment: Do **not** `erase` stuff in a `vector` whilst you're iterating through it.

Comment: the b as in Object b, not sure how safe that is to do though... Seeing as it is a class, with members, would it be better for me to delete it outside the loop, using a tag to find it in the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case you need an index while iterating vector's elements, instead of:

```
for (Object &a : objectDict) { ...
```

do traditional:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < objectDict.size(); ++i) { ...
```

and within the loop's body: instead of using reference `a`, you'll use `objectDict[i]`, then when you will need to erase element, you can do:

```
objectDict.erase(vec.begin() + i);
i--;
```

`i--` is used to move the index backwards by `1` so that when the next iteration increments it again, the element that follows right after the element that has been erased is not skipped.

Comment: This one worked, but it didnt before hence i was using the obscure method. Maybe i'd written something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to simply build a separate vector containing the indexes of elements to erase later.  Once you've finished going through the regular vector, loop in reverse order through the "to be removed" vector (in reverse because you don't want to invalidate the indexes as you go), and erase them.

Alternatively, as you iterate over the original vector, select the elements you want to *keep*, and copy them to another vector.  At the very end, swap the two vectors (which is cheap).  This will work better if you have relatively many elements to delete, on average.

Comment: You asked me to write the code for you within two minutes of my posting the outline for the solution.  That means you didn't try to write the code yourself.  Try.